# Bulk Import of CSV Data Into a Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition Table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

Can you explain, at a newbie friendly level, how to bulk import data from a CSV file into a table within a Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition? I am still at the stage of creating a C# front end to a MS SQL Server CE backend database. This is using  MS SQL Server CE 3.5 within Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate Edition if it matters). I may prefer to do it via a GUI database designer, for ease, though I would welcome SQL commands if it is necessary. This will be done once as the developer, it does not need to be used by the end-user.

I have already done both a google search and Stackoverflow search but have still not succeeded at what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox VS add-in to import (generate INSERT statements) a CSV file to a SQL Server Compact Table - http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com

Comment: +1 highly recommend - excellent stuff, Erik! Thanks for sharing with the world!

Comment: Thanks, I will soon release command line versions of the CSV import, to allow imports of larger CSV files to work without OOM errors

Comment: CSV project now published at http://csv2sqlce.codeplex.com (source code only just now)

Comment: Importing 1M rows just throws out of memory exceptions.

Comment: Rogler: please log an issue on Codeplex with more information, please http:/sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

Once I needed to perform bulk data import into SQL compact I used [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) tool for it. You can easily formulate your query in LINQ and you can easily chunk your data from CSV file by using `File.ReadAllLines()`, `String.Split(chardelimiters, StringSplitOptions)` and `Convert.ToInt32()/.ToDouble()` etc.

Comment: Just using split on CSV data is more than a bit simplistic. What about delimiters inside strings etc. You really need a CSV library or some cool regex to parse the CSV.

Comment: @ProfK The question was about bulk import to SQL, not about CSV parsing. Luckily LinqPAD supports NuGET packages and one can use some of the packages for data processing to read complex CSV...

Comment: A bulk import to SQL is useless unless the data was properly parsed. But, I have since been enlightened as to the `TextFieldParser`, hidden in the `VisualBasic` namespace, and it is highly configurable for fine tuning the CSV parsing.